# Warning assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-allocation

So I was messing around with dynamic allocation to get a better understanding of it and I encountered the " warning assignment from incompatible pointer type " warning twice in my code, and i have no clue why.

Basically what i am trying to do is to dynamically allocate a queue of dynamically allocated 2-dimensional arrays.

First warning:

```
int * int_alloc_2d(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){
    int **array;
    int i;
    array = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        array[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cols);
    return array;
}
```

The first warning appears at the `return array;` line. This function is meant to dynamically allocate a 2-dimensional array

Second warning:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QUEUE *queue;
    queue = (QUEUE *)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));
    int **a;
    a = int_alloc_2d(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

The second warning appears at the `a = int_alloc_2d(2,2);` line. Here i am just allocating memory for the queue ( just 1 block ) and allocating a 2x2 2-dimensional array in the "a" variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You try to return `int **array` in function that returns `int *`. And then you try to assign this `int *` returned to `int **a` pointer. Change your function to return `int **` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Count the number of `*`s. They aren't just for decoration!

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array! A pointer is not an array (and vice versa). And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: "assignment from incompatible pointer type" is actually an error;   for some reason gcc writes "warning" instead

Comment: Why did he got down voted? Just for missing of *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the warning because the function is declared to return `int*` (one-asterisk pointer) but you are returning a pointer to pointer `int**`, a two-asterisk pointer.

You can fix this by declaring the function return type as `int**`:

```
int ** int_alloc_2d(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){
    int **array;
    int i;
    array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        array[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*cols);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: oh, ok, i got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: " two-asterisk pointer" is quite miss leading. Why not use the correct term: "pointer to pointer" (it is even shorter).

Comment: @Olaf I used both terms. The colloquial one provides a more graphical description, though.